# How can I reduce code duplication when using inheritance in relation to exceptions?

Tags: python, inheritance, exception

I have a class.

```
class IncorrectOfferDetailsOfferException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, offer):
        self.offerName = offer[0]
        self.offerType = offer[1]
        self.message = "Offer \"" + self.offerName + "\" could not be completed. It appears to be of type \"" + self.offerType + "\", but this may be what is wrong and causing the exception."
        super(IncorrectOfferDetailsOfferException, self).__init__(self.message)
```

I want to write a more general class to expand it.

```
class BadOfferException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, offer):
        self.offerName = offer[0]
        self.offerType = offer[1]
        self.message = "Offer \"" + self.offerName + "\" caused a problem."
```

How can I relate those two together to remove the redundant code and override the more general message text with the more specific one? You know, class inheritance. I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how to use `super` the right way to do this.

Comment: First, for inheritance, the key question isn't how to share code, it's whether one is a subtype of the other. If you do `except BadOfferException:`, should that catch an `IncorrectOfferDetailsOfferException`? If so, then make `IncorrectOfferDetailsOfferException` a subclass of `BadOfferException`. If not, there are other ways to share code—a mixin class, a class decorator, a helper function… So, decide that first, and then we can help you with the next step.

Comment: @abarnert IncorrectOfferDetailsOfferException should be a subclass of BadOfferException. I don't understand how to do that and use the former to summon a specialized version of the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a method that is overriden by the sub-type:

```
class BadOfferException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, offer):
        self.offerName = offer[0]
        self.offerType = offer[1]
        self.message = self._construct_message()
        super(BadOfferException, self).__init__(self.message)

    def _construct_message(self):
        return 'Offer "{}" caused a problem'.format(self.offerName)


class IncorrectOfferDetailsOfferException(BadOfferException):
    def _construct_message(self):
        return 'Offer "{}" could not be completed. It appears to be of type "{}", but this may be what is wrong and causing the exception.'.format(self.offerName, self.offerType)
```

Then when you raise `IncorrectOfferDetailsOfferException` it just "works"

Comment: I love this. Seems clever and really does get the job done. Thank you. I understand this.

Answer (score 2):

First, the way you make a subclass is through the base class list at the top:

```
class BadOfferException(Exception):
    # etc.

class IncorrectOfferDetailsOfferException(BadOfferException):
    # etc.
```

I just replaced `Exception` with `BadOfferException`. (We don't need *both*, because `BadOfferException` is already a subclass of `Exception`) And you have to declare the superclass first, and the subclass afterward, so I switched the order.

---

Now, you'll want to make the implementation of the superclass to be a little more generic, so the subclass can override only the part it cares about. The only thing that's different is the message, right? So allow that to be passed in:

```
class BadOfferException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, offer, message=None):
        self.offerName = offer[0]
        self.offerType = offer[1]
        if message is None:
            message = "Offer \"" + self.offerName + "\" caused a problem."
        self.message = message
```

And now, that's all you have to pass via `super`. That means we can't use `offerName` and `offerType`, since they haven't been defined yet, but that isn't a problem here:

```
class IncorrectOfferDetailsOfferException(BadOfferException):
    def __init__(self, offer):
        message = "Offer \"" + offer[0] + "\" could not be completed. It appears to be of type \"" + offer[1] + "\", but this may be what is wrong and causing the exception."
        super(IncorrectOfferDetailsOfferException, self).__init__(offer, message)
```

That's all you need to do.

---

But while we're at it, you might want to make `BadOfferException` into a nicer subclass of `Exception`. People expect to be able to see the `args` on an `Exception` instance—it's not mandatory; you can leave it off and it'll just be an empty tuple, but it is nice. You can do that by calling `super(BadOfferException, self).__init__(offer)`.

Comment: This is a clean solution.

Comment: @SmallBlueGarbageCollector I think salparadise's is cleaner, and more powerful, for many use cases. This is the _simplest_ solution, but it's not necessarily the best.